# Why does array content get wiped and reset to the first result for a recursive function?

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, permutation

The issues stems from the output.append(a) on the third line.  This program would ideally output 6 unique permutations of the input string, but instead returns 6 of the first result in the recursive loop.  I realize exiting the recursion may have something to do with the array being modified, but how can I circumvent this issue to be able to return an array of solutions?

```
def permute(a, l, r, output):
    if l==r:
        output.append(a)
    else:
        for i in range(l,r+1):
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l]
            permute(a, l+1, r,output)
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l] # backtrack
```

## Driver program to test the above function

```
string = "ABC"
output = []
n = len(string)
a = list(string)
permute(a, 0, n-1,output)
print(output)
```

For reference, this is what the output looks like:

```
[['A', 'C', 'B']]
[['B', 'A', 'C'], ['B', 'A', 'C']]
[['B', 'C', 'A'], ['B', 'C', 'A'], ['B', 'C', 'A']]
[['C', 'B', 'A'], ['C', 'B', 'A'], ['C', 'B', 'A'], ['C', 'B', 'A']]
[['C', 'A', 'B'], ['C', 'A', 'B'], ['C', 'A', 'B'], ['C', 'A', 'B'], ['C', 'A', 'B']]
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

When the output should be:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'C', 'B']
['B', 'A', 'C']
['B', 'C', 'A']
['C', 'B', 'A']
['C', 'A', 'B']
```

Comment: I don't know what exactly your code is doing, but this part is suspicious: `output+=(permute(a, l+1, r,output))`. You are sending the same `output` to the recursive call, and it is going to modify it, there is not need for `+=`. It shuold probably be just `permute(a, l+1, r,output)`.

Comment: `permute` doesn't return anything, yet you're appending `output` to its return value: `output+=(permute(a, l+1, r,output))`

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was just code I was experimenting with and forgot about.  It should be good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the line

`output.append(a)`

it looks fine, but later on the list `a` changes, and when you append it to `output` again, the previous `a` (that you already appended) changes.

To solve the problem, you can simply use shallow copy. Write this instead:

```
output.append(a[:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know there is an excisting function in python?

```
import itertools 

listA = ["A", "B", "C"]
perm = itertools.permutations(listA) 

for i in list(perm): 
    print(i)
```

Result:

```
('A', 'B', 'C')
('A', 'C', 'B')
('B', 'A', 'C')
('B', 'C', 'A')
('C', 'A', 'B')
('C', 'B', 'A')
```

Comment: Yeah I know it exists, this is just for backtracking permutation practice as this is an issue I'm running into a lot with most backtracking solutions.